# How to convert unicode set from db to characters?

Tags: c#

I need to convert unicode characters that I take from the database field to a string value. In the database field unicode characters are in format U+0024 and next I get \u0024 format but I cannot convert it.

```
string a = "U+0024";
string b = a.Remove(0, 2);
string c = @"\u" + b;
string d = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(c);
Console.WriteLine(d);
// There is \u0024 in output
string e =System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(\u0024);
Console.WriteLine(e);
//There is $ in output that I would like to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings you got from your DB seems to be Unicode codepoints, as they are in the format `U+XXXX`.

There is a very useful method called [`char.ConvertFromUtf32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.convertfromutf32?view=netframework-4.8) that converts a Unicode code point to a string containing a single `char`, or a surrogate pair of `char`s.

This method accepts an `int` as parameter, so you would need to convert your `b` string (which is in hexadecimal) into an `int`.

```
int codepoint = Convert.ToInt32(b, 16);
```

Then, pass it to `ConvertFromUtf32`:

```
string result = char.ConvertFromUtf32(codepoint);
```